# Capture a video stream

Tags: video, streaming

I have set up a Raspberry Pi with a camera module to stream a video like a surveillance camera.  I would like to capture that stream to a video file with another device on the network running 19.04.  This seems fairly straightforward as the video stream has an ip address on the LAN which I can access.

What methods could be used to automate this process and save the video files on a daily basis?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: To close reviewers. I believe this question is generic and any answer it will receive may work for multiple releases.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a *virtual video lookpack device* with [v412 loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/README.md):

```
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
sudo depmod -a
```

Then send the video file into that device with

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Comment: Should I just put the second command in crontab to start at a certain time every day?  If so, I cannot see anything in the documentation to specify an end time to stop the stream.  This particular camera only works from sunrise to sunset so I do not need it to run all the time.

Comment: My friend, that's a separate question. The intent of StackExchange is to compile an infobase of resolved questions and answers; so, they want small, atomic, questions which are on-topic (ref. the above suggestion to use 18.04 LTS instead of interim releases which only last 9 mos.) Since they pay the bills, we're obliged to ask you to make that a second question, something like "how do I use crontab to end this at sunset?" That begs a third question of "how do I tell crontab just when sunrise and sunset are at my location?" Questions, questions, questions, we're here to help you with questions.

Comment: My apologies - I am just a little unsure of what exactly I am creating here.  I believe I was able to set this up as directed and I had to then install ffmpeg as well.  After doing this and running the last command I received the error, "vid1.mp4: No such file or directory".

Comment: Hmm. Please look into https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/blob/master/README.md and see how it labels the stream. My apologies for the incomplete answer, but I'm dancing as fast as I can.

Comment: In the dev directory there is an item called video0.  I get the same error when modifying the command above to that location (your command directed it to /dev/video2).